# Calculate the sum of the values of a json object represented by a string

Tags: mysql

I have a question like this looking forward to answering.
As in the table above, in mysql, how can I calculate the total value of a in key2??

```
Key1 | Key2
-----|-----------------------
VL1  | [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}]
-----|-----------------------
VL2  | [{"a": 6, "b": 5, "c": 0}]
-----|-----------------------
VL3  | [{"a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 9}]
```

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: I use  database mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work in MySQL v8 and onward.

```
select sum(json_extract(json_extract(key2,'$[0]'),'$.a')) as a_sum
from t;
```

Here is a db fiddle link (MySQL 8) - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=012de5c6d055f5e4c9879b6f83aa3f89

Here is a db fiddle link using oracle function “json_value” to perform same task (just for reference) - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a6e565d2bf7f0c79afb5b4b1a98ad9a